# Get Extended File Attributes in .NET Core App

Tags: c#, file, attributes

I need to get the computer attribute of a file in dotnet core (cross-platform) app. I've been googling for a while now and can't seem to find a good answer.

[image]

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

I did find this library: https://github.com/pierresprim/Windows-API-Code-Pack

It claims to support net core, but when I try to build my linux docker image, it fails:

/usr/share/dotnet/sdk/3.1.418/Sdks/Microsoft.NET.Sdk/targets/Microsoft.NET.Sdk.FrameworkReferenceResolution.targets(283,5): error NETSDK1073: The FrameworkReference 'Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App.WindowsForms' was not recognized [/src/myproject.csproj]